# How to scrape data from USDA website in rvest´s R?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I need to scrape the data from this url https://apps.fas.usda.gov/export-sales/corn.htm but I didn´t have success:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/export-sales/corn.htm"

page <- read_html(url)


df <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame()

>df
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: The table is pure text.  Instead of trying to scrape this, use the API service, find additional information here: https://apps.fas.usda.gov/opendataweb/home

Comment: Or to get started use this: `page %>% 
  html_node(xpath = "//pre") %>% 
  html_text() `

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(pagedown)
library(pdftools)
chrome_print(input = "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/export-sales/corn.htm",
             output = "C:\\stackoverflow101.pdf")

text <- pdftools::pdf_text("C:\\stackoverflow101.pdf")
text <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\r\n|\n"))
text

[1] "CORN - UNMILLED                                      MARKETING YEAR 09/01 - 08/31"
 [2] "   OUTSTANDING EXPORT SALES AND EXPORTS BY COUNTRY, REGION AND MARKETING YEAR"    
 [3] "1000 METRIC TONS        AS OF September 8 2022"                                   
 [4] "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" 
 [5] "                      :       CURRENT MARKETING YEAR         :NEXT MARKETING YEAR"
 [6] "                        ---------------------------------------------------------"
 [7] "                      :OUTSTANDING SALES:ACCUMULATED EXPORTS: OUTSTANDING SALES"  
 [8] "                        ---------------------------------------------------------"
 [9] "   DESTINATION        :THIS WEEK: YR AGO:THIS WEEK: YR AGO :SECOND YR: THIRD YR"  
[10] "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" 
[11] "                      :"                                                          
[12] "EUROPEAN UNION - 27   :    105.2      0.1          *       *        0.0       0.0"
[13] "   ITALY              :    105.0      0.0        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[14] "   U KING             :      0.2      0.1          *       *        0.0       0.0"
[15] "                      :"                                                          
[16] "JAPAN                 :    908.8   1686.5          *       *        0.0       0.0"
[17] "                      :"                                                          
[18] "TAIWAN                :     89.3    153.5        3.9     1.0        0.0       0.0"
[19] "                      :"                                                          
[20] "CHINA                 : 3223.4 11901.2         137.1     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[21] "                      :"                                                          
[22] "OTHER ASIA AND OCEANIA:     40.3     72.8        0.1     0.4        0.0       0.0"
[23] "   HG KONG            :      0.1      1.1          *     0.2        0.0       0.0"
[24] "   KOR REP            :      6.6     71.5        0.1     0.2        0.0       0.0"
[25] "   MALAYSA            :      1.0      0.0        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[26] "   PHIL               :      2.7      0.2        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[27] "   QATAR              :      0.0      0.0          *     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[28] "   S ARAB             :     30.0      0.0        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[29] "                      :"                                                          
[30] "WESTERN HEMISPHERE    : 5975.7     7991.2      322.5   358.4       90.5       0.0"
[31] "   BARBADO            :      8.0      6.3        4.4     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[32] "   C RICA             :    214.3    349.8        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[33] "   CANADA             :     35.6    556.0        1.9    33.6        0.0       0.0"
[34] "   COLOMB             :    182.0    854.2       10.8     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[35] "   DOM REP            :     33.0     35.8        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[36] "   GUATMAL            :    291.1    433.7        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[37] "   HAITI              :      0.0      2.3        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[38] "   HONDURA            :    196.4    214.8       71.1     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[39] "   JAMAICA            :     53.6     82.9        2.8     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[40] "   LW WW I            :      1.5      4.7        0.9     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[41] "   MEXICO             : 4723.2     4929.2      190.8   317.6       90.5       0.0"
[42] "   NICARAG            :      0.0    128.7       18.9     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[43] "   PANAMA             :     93.3    245.5        5.6     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[44] "   SALVADR            :    129.4    120.0       15.4     7.2        0.0       0.0"
[45] "   TRINID             :      0.0     15.4        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[46] "   VENEZ              :     14.5     12.0        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[47] "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" 
[48] "TOTAL KNOWN           : 10342.7 21805.3        463.6   359.9       90.5       0.0"
[49] "TOTAL UNKNOWN         : 1494.9     2407.5        0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0"
[50] "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" 
[51] "TOTAL KNOWN & UNKNOWN : 11837.7 24212.8        463.6   359.9       90.5       0.0"
[52] "EXPORTS FOR OWN ACCT :         -        -        0.0     0.0          -         -"
[53] "OPTIONAL ORIGIN       :      0.0    170.0          -       -        0.0       0.0"
[54] "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Great! but how can I convert all this data to dataframe in R ?

Comment: You can use regular expressions with the R package stringr. I will add an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of my previous answer :

```
library(pagedown)
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
chrome_print(input = "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/export-sales/corn.htm",
             output = "C:\\stackoverflow101.pdf")

text <- pdftools::pdf_text("C:\\stackoverflow101.pdf")
text <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\r\n|\n"))
text <- text[-(1 : 10)]
text <- text[-44]
text <- text[text != "                      :"]
text <- text[text != "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"]
regex <- "(.*:)|([:space:]*(\\d{1,4}\\.\\d{1}|\\*|-))"
list_Numbers <- stringr::str_extract_all(text, pattern = regex)
mat_Numbers <- do.call("rbind", list_Numbers)
mat_Numbers

[,1]                      [,2]         [,3]          [,4]             [,5]       [,6]          [,7]        
 [1,] "EUROPEAN UNION - 27   :" "    105.2"  "      0.1"   "          *"    "       *" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [2,] "   ITALY              :" "    105.0"  "      0.0"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [3,] "   U KING             :" "      0.2"  "      0.1"   "          *"    "       *" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [4,] "JAPAN                 :" "    908.8"  "   1686.5"   "          *"    "       *" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [5,] "TAIWAN                :" "     89.3"  "    153.5"   "        3.9"    "     1.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [6,] "CHINA                 :" " 3223.4"    "1901.2"      "         137.1" "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [7,] "OTHER ASIA AND OCEANIA:" "     40.3"  "     72.8"   "        0.1"    "     0.4" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [8,] "   HG KONG            :" "      0.1"  "      1.1"   "          *"    "     0.2" "        0.0" "       0.0"
 [9,] "   KOR REP            :" "      6.6"  "     71.5"   "        0.1"    "     0.2" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[10,] "   MALAYSA            :" "      1.0"  "      0.0"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[11,] "   PHIL               :" "      2.7"  "      0.2"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[12,] "   QATAR              :" "      0.0"  "      0.0"   "          *"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[13,] "   S ARAB             :" "     30.0"  "      0.0"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[14,] "WESTERN HEMISPHERE    :" " 5975.7"    "     7991.2" "      322.5"    "   358.4" "       90.5" "       0.0"
[15,] "   BARBADO            :" "      8.0"  "      6.3"   "        4.4"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[16,] "   C RICA             :" "    214.3"  "    349.8"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[17,] "   CANADA             :" "     35.6"  "    556.0"   "        1.9"    "    33.6" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[18,] "   COLOMB             :" "    182.0"  "    854.2"   "       10.8"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[19,] "   DOM REP            :" "     33.0"  "     35.8"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[20,] "   GUATMAL            :" "    291.1"  "    433.7"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[21,] "   HAITI              :" "      0.0"  "      2.3"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[22,] "   HONDURA            :" "    196.4"  "    214.8"   "       71.1"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[23,] "   JAMAICA            :" "     53.6"  "     82.9"   "        2.8"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[24,] "   LW WW I            :" "      1.5"  "      4.7"   "        0.9"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[25,] "   MEXICO             :" " 4723.2"    "     4929.2" "      190.8"    "   317.6" "       90.5" "       0.0"
[26,] "   NICARAG            :" "      0.0"  "    128.7"   "       18.9"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[27,] "   PANAMA             :" "     93.3"  "    245.5"   "        5.6"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[28,] "   SALVADR            :" "    129.4"  "    120.0"   "       15.4"    "     7.2" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[29,] "   TRINID             :" "      0.0"  "     15.4"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[30,] "   VENEZ              :" "     14.5"  "     12.0"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[31,] "TOTAL KNOWN           :" "0342.7"     "1805.3"      "        463.6"  "   359.9" "       90.5" "       0.0"
[32,] "TOTAL UNKNOWN         :" " 1494.9"    "     2407.5" "        0.0"    "     0.0" "        0.0" "       0.0"
[33,] "TOTAL KNOWN & UNKNOWN :" "1837.7"     "4212.8"      "        463.6"  "   359.9" "       90.5" "       0.0"
[34,] "EXPORTS FOR OWN ACCT :"  "         -" "        -"   "        0.0"    "     0.0" "          -" "         -"
[35,] "OPTIONAL ORIGIN       :" "      0.0"  "    170.0"   "          -"    "       -" "        0.0" "       0.0"
```